# Not able to get XSLT for-each sort working

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml and it transformed and sorted by Location:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:MT_testinput xmlns:ns0="urn:cad_poc">
  <Amendment>
    <ID>A1</ID>
    <Pointer>
      <Location>/Ship1/Comm1</Location>
    </Pointer>
    <Pointer>
      <Location>/Ship1/Comm2</Location>
    </Pointer>
  </Amendment>
  <Amendment>
    <ID>A2</ID>
    <Pointer>
      <Location>/Ship1/Comm2</Location>
    </Pointer>
    <Pointer>
      <Location>/Ship3/Comm1</Location>
    </Pointer>
  </Amendment>
</ns0:MT_testinput>
```

I tried the following xslt and not working:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    exclude-result-prefixes="ns0" 
    xmlns:ns0="urn:cad_poc" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    version="1.0"
>
  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
  <xsl:template match="MT_testinput">
    <xsl:for-each select="Amendment">
      <xsl:sort select="Pointer/Location"/>
      <Location>
        <xsl:value-of select="Pointer/Location"/>
      </Location>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Please add the expected output to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only thing you need to change is the match pattern: the `MT_testinput` element is in a namespace so the pattern is not matching. Change it to

```
<xsl:template match="p:MT_testinput" xmlns:p="urn:cad_poc">
```

Comment: I don''t think so. Is this your expected output? https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bEzkTcJ

Comment: It does work and Michael is right that the problem is the namespace. I have a hard time posting my xslt in this site with the character restriction.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort all `Location`s, with no regard to their parent `Pointer` and `Amendment`, try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="Amendment/Pointer">
            <xsl:sort select="Location"/>
            <Location>
                <xsl:value-of select="Location"/>
            </Location>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <Location>/Ship1/Comm1</Location>
  <Location>/Ship1/Comm1</Location>
  <Location>/Ship1/Comm2</Location>
  <Location>/Ship1/Comm2</Location>
  <Location>/Ship2/Comm1</Location>
  <Location>/Ship2/Comm2</Location>
  <Location>/Ship3/Comm1</Location>
  <Location>/Ship3/Comm1</Location>
  <Location>/Ship3/Comm2</Location>
</root>
```